# Add event listener to trigger the same function to dynamically created button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this jquery code,

```
 var next = 1;
$(".add-more").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).replaceWith("<button id='remove" + (next) + "' class='btn btn-danger remove-me pull-right'>-</button>");
    var addto = "#field" + next;
    next = next + 1;
    var str = "<tr id='field" + next + "'><td><input autocomplete='off' class='input form-control' id='item" + next + "' name='item" + next + "' type='text' data-items='8'/></td>"+
                "<td><input autocomplete='off' class='input form-control' id='desc" + next + "' name='desc" + next + "' type='text' data-items='8'/></td>"+
                "<td><input autocomplete='off' class='input form-control' id='qty" + next + "' name='qty" + next + "' type='text' data-items='8'/></td>"+
                "<td><input autocomplete='off' class='input form-control' id='ucost" + next + "' name='ucost" + next + "' type='text' data-items='8'/></td>"+
                "<td><input autocomplete='off' class='input form-control' id='tcost" + next + "' name='tcost" + next + "' type='text' data-items='8'/></td>"+
                "<td><input autocomplete='off' class='input form-control' id='type" + next + "' name='type" + next + "' type='text' data-items='8'/></td>"+
                "<td><button id='b1' class='btn add-more pull-right' type='button'>+</button></td></tr>";
    $(addto).after(str);
    $("#count").val(next); 
    $('.remove-me').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var fieldNum = this.id.charAt(this.id.length-1);
            var fieldID = "#field" + fieldNum;
            $(this).remove();
            $(fieldID).remove();
    });
});
```

This lines of codes make a user able to create multiple fields.
If the user click the "Add" Button, it will create multiple fields.
This will also change the "Add" button to "Remove" button. And add another "Add " button.

My problem here is, the dynamically created #b1 button don't have event listener.

I tried to use this line of code,

```
$("#field" + next).attr('data-source',$(addto).attr('data-source'));
```

but it is not working. My idea is like this one,

http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/dynamic-form-fields-add-amp-remove

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for dynamically created elements use

```
$(document).on('click', '.add-more', function() {...};
```

instead of

```
$('.add-more').click(...
```

this is called event delegation, you add event to document (or a parent element, which exists from page load) and then trigger when its child, which you specify as an argument (in this case '.add-more') is clicked